# Reading Multiple lines in C

Tags: c

So I am trying to read input from a text file and print the exact same thing I read in C.So this below is the input followed by enter:

input:  `Hi`
output: `Hi`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *inputString(FILE *fp, size_t size) {
    //The size is extended by the input with the value of the provisional
    char *str;
    int ch;
    size_t len = 0;
    str = realloc(NULL, sizeof(char) * size); //size is start size
    if (!str)
        return str;
    while (EOF != (ch = fgetc(fp)) && ch != '\n') {
        str[len++] = ch;
        if (len == size) {
            str = realloc(str, sizeof(char) * (size += 16));
            if (!str)
                return str;
        }
    }
    str[len++] = '\0';

    return realloc(str, sizeof(char) * len);
}

int main(void) {
    char *m;

    // printf("input string : ");
    m = inputString(stdin, 10);
    printf("%s\n", m);

    free(m);
    return 0;
}
```

For this input:

```
    Hi, this is the first line 
    This is the second line
    This is the third line \n
```

This is the output I expected:

```
    Hi, this is the first line 
    This is the second line
    This is the third line \n
```

This is what I got:

```
    Hi, this is the first line
```

It makes sense that the code is printing only the first line, but since the condition in the guard will no longer be true after hitting the new line, but I don't know how to structure my code so it reads line by line and prints them respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the code to read each line, remove `&& ch != '\n'` from the condition of the while loop.

Also, the code is reading from stdin instead of a file. Use [fopen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/) to read from a file, i.e. `m = inputString(fopen("filename.txt", "r"), 512)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int cnt=0;
        char buf[1024];
        FILE *fptr=stdin;
        printf("Input: \n");
        char ch=fgetc(fptr);
        buf[cnt++]=ch;
        while(ch!='$')
        {
                buf[cnt++]=ch;
                ch=fgetc(fptr);
        }
        buf[cnt++]='$';
        buf[cnt]='\0';
        printf("Output:\n");
        fputs(buf,stdout);
        fclose(fptr);

}
```

I have put '$' as the delimiter.
I have used an extra buffer as newline is bound to EOF for stdin. So if I print out the character immediately it comes out of loop.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is repeat the process as long as you can read lines:

```
int main(void) {
    char *m;

    // printf("input strings: ");
    while ((m = inputString(stdin, 10)) != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", m);
        free(m);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For this to work correctly, you must return `NULL` at end of file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *inputString(FILE *fp, size_t size) {
    //The size is extended by the input with the value of the provisional
    int ch;
    size_t len = 0;
    char *str = malloc(size);

    if (str == NULL)
        return NULL;

    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        if (len + 2 > size) {
            char *new_str = realloc(str, size += 16);
            if (!new_str) {
                free(str);
                return NULL;
            str = new_str;
        }
        str[len++] = ch;
    }
    if (c == EOF && len == 0) {
        /* at end of file */
        free(str);
        return NULL;
    }
    str[len++] = '\0';
    return realloc(str, len);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of:

```
while(EOF!=(ch=fgetc(fp))&& ch != '\n' ){
    // stuff
}
```

you could do:

```
while(EOF!=(ch=fgetc(fp))){
    // stuff
    if (ch == '\n') break;
}
```

Now you have consumed the newline.

Comment: I actually did what you proposed at first,but upon reading the char m in my print I only get this message on the console "[4]+  Stopped "

Comment: That sound like your shell job control. did you type the suspend character (probably Ctrl-Z) ?